# RabbitMQ autoheal mode

Tags: rabbitmq

due to doc
https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html#automatic-handling

`"In autoheal mode RabbitMQ will automatically decide on a winning partition if a partition is deemed to have occurred, and will restart all nodes that are not in the winning partition"`

`"autoheal: appropriate when are more concerned with continuity of service than with data consistency across nodes."`

but I can’t understand this description... :(

Please tell me what happens in autoheal mode - if there are three nodes in a cluster, and one of them crashes (Network partition detected), messages are saved and sent to other nodes, and this third crashed node is rebooted?